# How to center text vertically, that has position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a hover hide effect. My goal is here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/BeastlyCoder/pen/OqoPmb)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #123456;
}

#object {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  border: #333 3px solid;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 750px
}

#spoiler {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.3s opacity linear;
  z-index: 5;
}

#spoiler:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#big {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
/*   top: 0; */
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div id="object">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae aperiam praesentium commodi optio ab saepe deserunt ullam et sequi doloremque consectetur hic laudantium inventore dignissimos, placeat modi nobis est nostrum.</p>
  <div id="spoiler"></div>
  <p id="big">Hover to show</p>
</div>
```

I want to make the text that says "hover to show" to be centered vertically, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center vertically an absolute element inside the relative positioned parent, you can use `top:50%` ( 50% means 1/2 parent height ) together with `transform: translateY(-50%)` ( 50% means 1/2 of element height ) .

This way it will be centered vertically even if parent and/or this element changes  height

I added one line of css to hide the ' green ' div when user hovers over the ' spoiler '

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #123456;
}

#object {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  border: #333 3px solid;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 750px
}

#spoiler {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.3s opacity linear;
  z-index: 5;
}

#spoiler:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

  

#big {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 20;
}

#spoiler:hover + #big {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="object">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae aperiam praesentium commodi optio ab saepe deserunt ullam et sequi doloremque consectetur hic laudantium inventore dignissimos, placeat modi nobis est nostrum.</p>
  <div id="spoiler"></div>
  <p id="big">Hover to show</p>
</div>
```